# Javascript switch statement with input text

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

```
<script>
document.getElementById("clicker").onclick = function () {
    var scenario = document.getElementById('scenario');
    switch (scenario) {
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "How are you?";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "whatevers";
            break;
        case 3:
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "i don't know";
            break;
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "today is your lucky day";
            break;
        default:
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "This is the worst case scenario";
    }
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="scenario" />
<input type="submit" id="clicker" />
<p id="answer"></p>
```

So here i'm trying to basically have a text field where the user will type in some value
based on that value, the script will then look at cases and determine what to output in the paragraph element.

Please advise how i should correct this code.

Comment: I see that you are new to stackoverflow. If any of the answers are helpful, please click accept on the one you think is best. If the answers can be improved, comment on them about it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this:

```
<script>

document.getElementById("clicker").onclick = function() {
    var scenario = document.getElementById('scenario').value; 
    var answers = {
        "1": "How are you?",
        "2": "whatevers",
        "3": "i don't know",
        "4": "today is your lucky day",
        "5": "This is the worse case scenario"
    };
    var str = answers[scenario];
    if (str) {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = str;
    }
}

</script>
```

The main fix is that you get the value from an `<input>` field with the `.value` property.

The rest of the change is a more efficient way to map a typed string to the question.

---

If your scenarios are always simple sequential numbers, then you could use an array lookup too:

```
<script>

document.getElementById("clicker").onclick = function() {
    var scenario = document.getElementById('scenario').value; 
    var answers = [
        "How are you?",
        "whatevers",
        "i don't know",
        "today is your lucky day",
        "This is the worse case scenario"
    ];
    if (scenario) {
        var str = answers[+scenario - 1];
        if (str) {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = str;
        }
}

</script>
```

---

In general, if you can find a way to express a switch statement as either an array lookup or an object lookup, you will end up with cleaner, smaller and easier to maintain code.

Comment: +1 but why not an array `answers = [...]` and then `answers[+scenario]`?

Comment: @elclanrs - If the scenarios are only sequential numbers, then an array lookup would also work fine.  I added that option too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using, You need add `value` property.

```
var scenario = document.getElementById('scenario').value;
```

instead of

```
var scenario = document.getElementById('scenario');
```

Answer (score 0):

jfriend00 nailed it regarding the key lookup approach. I am including my answer also, as I have some additional suggestions. [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/IlEFezaD/1/edit)

```
/* try to avoid getting your element references inside of functions.
 * If you get them earlier, you don't need to keep searching the dom on each function call 
 */    
var input = document.getElementById('scenario');
var p = document.getElementById('answer');

var responses = [
  "How are you?",
  "whatevers",
  "i don't know",
  "today is your lucky day",
  "This is the worst case scenario"
];

/* I recommend using keyup rather than having to click on a button - save your user some work! */
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var response;
  if (responses[this.value]) {
    response = responses[this.value];
  }
  else { //do something if you don't have a response
    response = 'No response for this.';
  }
  p.textContent = response;
});
```

Comment: I see some interesting ideas here. but The purpose here for me is to learn how to use switch statements and get input unobstrusively.

Comment: The problem is that this is a bad use for a `switch`... did a teacher assign this?? @RayC

Comment: actually, i already have my degree. i'm just self studying and coming up with a different task each day to teach myself. basically, the switch statement is the only one i have some trouble with getting to work unobstrusively.

Comment: @RayC well, your switch statement is fine in the above code. You just need to get the value, not just the element, like this: `document.getElementById('scenario').value;`

Answer (score 0):

// try my answer , hope you will have a better experience

```js
function inputCSS() {
  var text;
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("demo").value;
  if (inputValue < 10) {
   alert ("you can't input a value lower than 10");
  }
  else if (inputValue > 100) {
    alert ("you can't input a value bigger than 100");
  }
}
function awal() {
  var sampleText ;
  var checkInputValue = document.getElementById("demo").value;
  var kopa = Number(checkInputValue);
  if (kopa === 61) {
    sampleText = "hurrah! you have won the lottery";
  }
  else if (kopa > 51 && kopa < 71) {
    sampleText = "too close";
  }
  else {
    sampleText = "bad luck!";
  }
  document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML = sampleText;
}
```

```css
#demo:invalid {
  border-color:  red;
}
input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="demo" min="10" max="100" value="50"/>
<button onclick="awal()" onmouseover="inputCSS()">submit</button>
<p id="sample"></p>
```