# Switch Statements in Javascript based on input text value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to accomplish the following currently and am not very familiar with `Javascript` so I am hoping I could get some good suggestions and answers for the following as I have gotten such great help with my `Javescript` questions here before.

Basically I have an input field where the user will enter a value. Once that value is entered I want to provide the user some information in a div, prior to them submitting the value to the Ajax handler. I would also like to have the values presented to them on each change of the input fields text. I have 3 different types of data being submitted so for each type I would like to present different information sets to the user based on what their input contains. For this I use a switch, but the switch is currently not working as it appears below.

```
function createLinks() {
    var sv = document.getElementById('sv').value // Input Text
    var div = document.getElementById('svResult');

    switch (true) {
    case (sv.indexOf('1') >= 0):
        div.innerHTML="1 Links: ";
        break;
    case (sv.indexOf('2') >= 0):
        div.innerHTML="2 Links: ";
        break;
    case (sv.indexOf('3') >= 0):
        div.innerHTML="3 Links: ";
        break;
    }
//div.innerHTML=sv.value;
}

<div>
    <form>
        <label for="sv">Server:</label>
        <input type="text" id="sv" size="16" title="Coming Soon" onchange="createLinks()"/>
        <input type="submit" style="margin-left: 10px;" value="Search" class="button1"/>
    </form>
    <div id="svResult"></div>
</div>
```

When I just display the sv.value in the div assigned to the div variable it displays correctly, but when the switch is introduced I do not get any output. The switch is based on the return of each `case` statement being either true or false, but there is probably something simple I am missing.

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184744/javascript-switch-statement-with-input-text) which helped get the `input` value into the variable correctly, but focuses  more on `if` statements.

Comment: Not enough jquery, you should really use jquery.

Comment: @Naren This question is not about jQuery.

Comment: @MattGreen your code works when adapted to work in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdu5v/

Comment: It's JavaScript, not "Javescript"

Comment: That's a weird way to use `switch`, even if it works. Why not use `if` like a normal programmer?

Comment: Why not use string concatenation...there's no point in a control structure in the example.

Comment: Your code works as written for me (no special "adaptation" needed for the fiddle - I suspet @AlexWayne forgot to select No Wrap): http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mdu5v/4/

Comment: I am open to using `JQuery` or an `if` statement, but I am not familiar with those options so I would need to see an example. I guess I have to figure out why it works in the fiddle examples but not on the site. Is there a script include I need or anything?

Comment: @MattGreen -- Not familiar with `if` ? In that case, I would recommend a crash course in JS -- `if` is a pretty crucial part of programming :)

Comment: @MattGreen—the jQuery comment was sarcasm, it is irrelevant here.

Comment: @tymeJV a crash course in JS would probably be what I need. I know If very well, but I am working on a tiny bit of a site that will use `Javascript` for only this instance and `indexOf` along with other functions are all unfamiliar to me so I did not want to chain together a bunch of code I did not really understand.

Comment: Instead of `switch (value) case` you do `if (condition)` so `if (sv.indexOf('1') >= 0) { div.innerHTML = '1 Links: '; } else if (sv.indexOf('2') >= 0) { dv.innerHTML = '2 Links: '; } else if (sv.indexOf('3') >= 0) { dv.innerHTML = '3 Links: '; }` Of course, there is a clear pattern here that could easily be refined into a much more elegant approach than using `if blocks`.

Comment: @Naren Now that you have mentioned the JQuery I was hoping to incorporate the [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) functionality of JQuery onto this process as well if you where to want to submit a JQuery alternative to the above.

Comment: @crush wouldn't that solution be a switch? Or where you referring to something else completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML, there is no need for an ID attribute and form controls must have a name to be successful. You can also pass a reference to the element from the listener:

```
<input type="text" name="sv" size="16" title="Coming Soon" onchange="createLinks(this)">
```

Then the script can be something like:

```
function createLinks(el) {
  var value = el.value;
  var div = document.getElementById('svResult');

  if (value.indexOf('1') != -1) {
    div.innerHTML = '1 Link';

  } else if (value.indexOf('2') != -1) {
    div.innerHTML = '2 Links';

  } else if (value.indexOf('3') != -1) {
    div.innerHTML = '3 Links';
  }

  } else {
    div.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

The above will return on the first match, so an input of '123' will report "1 link". Also, the change event is dispatched when the control loses focus, which might be later than you want.

Comment: My script worked originally minus a syntax error I did not transcript into the question (good problem to have?), but your answer does illustrate another way of receiving the desired affects.